# Nuxt: Auth + Axios setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm struggling with the configuration of auth + Axios.

I'm currently working on our social login (FB and google). It half works.

First of all, I have my Axios instance configured as a plugin. We do have two instances, one that we use for general API requests and another one that we will use for logged user requests.

plugins/axios.js

```
export default function({ $axios, redirect, app }) {
  $axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.baseUrl
 
  $axios.defaults.headers = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.APIKey}`,
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    lang: app.i18n.locale
  }

  $axios.onError(error => {
    const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
    if (code === 400) {
      redirect('/400')
    }
    if (code === 404) {
      redirect('/404')
    }
    if (code === 500) {
      redirect('/500')
    }
  })
}
```

plugins/auth-axios.js

```
export default function({ $axios }, inject) {
  const authAxios = $axios.create()
  // authAxios.setToken('123', 'Bearer')

  inject('authAxios', authAxios)
}
```

The first client works perfectly in the whole app.

Now I'm configuring the auth plugin. When I log in through Facebook or google I need to take the response data of the logged user from the social network and send it to my API, expecting a user with the token as the response. This will be the user that I'll set in the auth plugin. Every time I log in with Facebook it appears to work well except when It arrives at the plugin code. $auth.loggedIn is always false.

I've made it work forcing $auth.fetchUser at the beginning of the code but it doesn't work well at all. It shows an Axios error when console.log($auth). This is my auth code:

plugins/auth.js

```
export default async function({ app: { $auth, $axios } }) {
  $auth.fetchUser()
  console.log($auth)
  if (!$auth.loggedIn) {
    return
  }

  const authStrategy = $auth.strategy.name
  if (authStrategy === 'facebook' || authStrategy === 'google') {
    if ($auth.user.google_id || $auth.user.fb_id) return

    try {
      const url = `/client/social`
      var postData
      if (authStrategy == 'facebook')
        postData = {
          name: $auth.user.name,
          email: $auth.user.email,
          fb_id: $auth.user.id,
          avatar: $auth.user.picture.data.url,
          birthday: $auth.user.birthday
        }
      else
        postData = {
          name: $auth.user.given_name,
          surname: $auth.user.family_name,
          email: $auth.user.email,
          google_id: $auth.user.sub,
          avatar: $auth.user.picture,
          locale: $auth.user.locale
        }
      const { data } = await $axios.post(url, postData)
      $auth.setToken('client', data.access_token)
      $auth.setUser(data.client)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
```

The console.log($auth) error:

```
'$state': {
    user: null,
    loggedIn: false,
    strategy: 'facebook'
  },
  error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'Authorization' of undefined
      at Function.setHeader (server.js:1556:42)
      at Oauth2Scheme._setToken (server.js:1014:31)
      at Oauth2Scheme.mounted (server.js:1001:12)
      at Auth.mounted (server.js:516:42)
      at Auth.init (server.js:459:18)
      at module.exports../.nuxt/auth/plugin.js._webpack_exports_.default (server.js:939:16)
      at createApp (server.js:2432:87)
}
```

And my auth module config:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

export const auth = {
  plugins: [
    // {
    //   src: '~/plugins/axios',
    //   ssr: true
    // },
    {
      src: '~/plugins/auth-axios',
      ssr: true
    },
    '~/plugins/auth.js'
  ],
  redirect: {
    login: '/',
    callback: '/callback'
  },
  strategies: {
    local: false,
    facebook: {
      client_id: '#############',
      userinfo_endpoint:
        'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=about,name,picture{url},email,birthday',
      scope: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_birthday']
    },
    google: {
      client_id:
        '#####################'
    }
  }
}
```

Seems that auth when login is trying to set the Axios token (also when I log out it tries to remove it) but it fails. If I go to the Chrome dev tools and debug it to see which Axios instance is trying to use for that. Every time is the main Axios instance and it's supposed to be accessible there.

Screenshot from DevTools:
[Screenshot from DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIEJt.jpg)

Does someone know what I'm missing? Can I prevent auth facebook strategy to update any Axios instance? Or, can I specify which Axios instance to update (set / remove token)?

EDIT: Forcing the $auth.fetchUser my auth plugin code does work but with the error mentioned before. When I try to logOut it doesn't work due to the same error when trying to remove the token automatically)

I'm going crazy with this issue for two weeks now.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I am facing the same issue there, my main axios instance is used for my ElasticSearch, and I want to have an other instance some my JWT authentication API. I think we need to override the constructor of the Request to inject our own instance. But I don't think it's possible, or just need to fork the module.